# access gitlab files through ajax request

Tags: gitlab

I would like to access the **raw files** in a repository of mine that is on gitlab through an ajax request. However, it's not working, I'm wondering if I have to setup my project accordingly or something. Obviously my project is `public`. This is the error message I get :

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Which means it's on their end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To understand `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, I highly recommend [How does Access-Control-Allow-Origin header work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work)

> When Site A tries to fetch content from Site B, Site B can send an
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header to tell the browser that
>   the content of this page is accessible to certain origins. (An origin
>   is a domain, plus a scheme and port number.) By default, Site B's
>   pages are not accessible to any other origin; using the
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin header opens a door for cross-origin
>   access by specific requesting origins.

If your GitLab is hosted on gitlab.com, I don't see a way to add your domain to response header.

The easiest solution is wrapping XMLHttpRequests to GitLab in requests to your application - and on the backend you will simply fetch and return data. For example, you won't send a XML request to `https://gitlab.com/pdaw/test/raw/master/README.md`, but to`https://my.app.com/fetch-file?file=pdaw/test/raw/master/README.md`. On the backend of the `fetch-file` action you will fetch and return raw data from `https://gitlab.com/pdaw/test/raw/master/README.md`

Comment: That's why I said it was on their end. Maybe if I change a setting on my gitlab account or smtg they add the header automatically. Thanks anyway... It seems pretty weird that they don't allow it tbh. I don't wanna go through their api just to do that

Comment: @Ced As I see, this problem is nagging, https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/24596 for example